# How to start Oracle 12c database when table space file was accidentally deleted

Tags: oracle

I've accidentally deleted a tablespace file and now Oracle 12c will not open.

How can I remove this tablespace from oracle without the database being open?

Answer (score 4):

If you have deleted the datafiles then you have to restore it from the physical backup if you don't want loose data.

[Performing Complete Recovery of a Tablespace](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmcomre.htm#BRADV89773)

The datafiles information is checked by Oracle during open database process. It means you can mount the database and make the datafile offline.

`ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE 'path to datafile' OFFLINE;`

`ALTER DATABASE OPEN;`

Answer (score 1):

ALTER DATABASE DATAFILE '/u02/oracle/rbdb1/stuff01.dbf' OFFLINE;